# Best way to make a "glowing" button in android java?

Tags: android, android-button, shadow, glow

I am using Android Java in Android Studio with this project. I am trying to make a pulsating shadow for my button. I want it so whenever the user clicks the wrong button, I bring attention to the button they should click by making pulsating a shadow. I have looked through many forums and posts with no success. If there is a different way to do this, please let me know. Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's some code I was working on:

```
newTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(start_stop_btn, "background", new ArgbEvaluator(), R.drawable.button_shadow, 0xff000000);
            colorFade.setDuration(7000);
            colorFade.start();
            start_stop_btn.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.button_shadow);
        }
    };
    Timer newTimer = new Timer();
    newTimer.schedule(newTimerTask, 0, 100);
```

button_shadow.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="#D6D6D6" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
            <shape>
                <gradient android:angle="270"
                    android:endColor="#E6E600" android:startColor="#FFFF00" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA" />
                <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide a code example for it! thnx! for what you have one till now! so we can tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such attribute in `Android`, to show a shadow. 
You can do a work around like this :

Take `LinearLayout` or `Framelayout` with grey color, under your `Button`, with `margin` at bottom and right equal to 1 or 2 `dp`.

Make it visible when wrong `Button` is clicked.

Thats the best I can suggest for your requirement.

My suggestion is to get a good animation to catch user attention though.

Comment: Try this : https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations
They are very easy to integrate.

Comment: Ok, new problem, when I use `com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1` like the page says it needs `ContextCompat` doesn't work. When I use  `com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1` `.with()` does not work. Does not work = Cannot resolve method x.
Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure about that. Works fine for me. It was just a suggestion. There are loads of other animations available. If you still want to use this, you can raise an issue in its Github. You will probably get reply in it.